# Creating Dynamic 3D Buffers in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: buffer, 3d, 3d-analyst, arcgis-pro, 3d-model

I am currently using ArcGIS Pro to model WiFi router signal distribution and I would like to use buffers to display them in a 3D format. I have used the Buffers 3D tool to create spherical buffers, however in the real world there are a lot of physical external factors that affect the range of the signal (i.e. walls, floors, ceilings, usage, construction materials, etc.). The buffers I have created sit within a constructed 3D building that has walls, ceilings, and floors. I would like to create a buffer that could recognize these physical structures, such as floors, walls, and ceilings, and reduce the buffer by a certain coefficient whenever it passes through one. I realize that this is quite a complex process, but I am looking for some simple solutions that could help make the model more realistic.